# Error reporting for Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

Is there a way to send notifications when an error happens in Dataflow ?

Is it possible to integrate it with something like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) ?

Or maybe with Stackdriver or Google Cloud's error reporting service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is possible through the following configuration:

- Dataflow logs are streamed into Google Cloud Logging.
- Create a custom log based metric in Google Cloud Logging.
- Create an alert policy in Google Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) based on the custom log based metric.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the only way at the moment. I couldn't make it work, so I raised a support ticket with Google, and they told me that creating log-based metrics is only available for the premium version of Stackdriver. More info: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#chargeable-resources